# Django: Use different templates on an inline when edit or add

Tags: django, templates, inline, subclass

Let's say I want to use a different template for the add page but not the edit. What would be the best way to accomplish that? I was thinking either subclassing add_view or change_view, or alternatively maybe subclass some InlineModelAdmin method. 
What's your guys take on this? Thanks.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: django, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty crappy solution but here is how I solved it:

```
class FooInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Foo

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None): 
       url = request.get_full_path()
       if '/add/' not in url:
           self.template = 'listing.html'
       return super(FooInline, self).get_fieldsets( request, obj)
```